Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when removing key from hashmap in Java
https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/
the problem occurs at the line:
hm.remove(currentGreatestValue);
class Solution {
    public int[] topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
            if (!hm.containsKey(nums[i])){
                hm.put(nums[i], 1);
            } else {
                int occurances = hm.get(nums[i]);
                occurances = occurances + 1;
                hm.put(nums[i], occurances);
            }
        }
   
        int mostOccuredValues[] = new int[k]; 

        Iterator hmIterator = hm.entrySet().iterator();

        int currentGreatestValue=0;
        int currentValue;

        int nextGreatestIndex=0;


        for (int i=0; i<k; i++){
            while (hmIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry mapElement = (Map.Entry)hmIterator.next();
                currentValue = (int)mapElement.getKey();
                if (currentValue>currentGreatestValue){
                    currentGreatestValue = currentValue;
                }
            }
            mostOccuredValues[nextGreatestIndex] = hm.get(currentGreatestValue);
            nextGreatestIndex = nextGreatestIndex + 1;
 
            hm.remove(currentGreatestValue);
        }

        return mostOccuredValues;
    }
}

want to remove key from hashmap to get the next greatest element while iterating

As an aside, and I hope it’s not disappointing. Your link also says Follow up: Your algorithm's time complexity must be better than O(n log n), where n is the array's size. You’re not there yet.

You will benefit from learning to use a debugger.

class Solution {
public int[] topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        if (!hm.containsKey(nums[i])){
            hm.put(nums[i], 1);
        } else {
            int occurances = hm.get(nums[i]);
            occurances = occurances + 1;
            hm.put(nums[i], occurances);
        }
    }

    int mostOccuredValues[] = new int[k]; 

    int currentValue;
    int currentKey;

    int nextGreatestIndex=0;


    for (int i=0; i<k; i++){
        int currentGreatestValue=0;
        int currentGreatestKey=0;
        
        Iterator hmIterator = hm.entrySet().iterator();
        while (hmIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry mapElement = (Map.Entry)hmIterator.next();
            currentValue = (int)mapElement.getValue();
            currentKey = (int)mapElement.getKey();
            
            if (currentValue>currentGreatestValue){
                currentGreatestValue = currentValue;
                currentGreatestKey = currentKey;
            }
        }

        mostOccuredValues[nextGreatestIndex] = currentGreatestKey;
        nextGreatestIndex = nextGreatestIndex + 1;

        hm.remove(currentGreatestKey);
    }

    return mostOccuredValues;
}

}

Thanks for the code. I haven’t read through it, and I don’t know whether nor how it may answer your question. Please provide some explanation along with the code.

Why this was downvoted its the correct answer and part of the answer is from the null pointer fixed, this is the complete leetcode problem

I downvoted because code with no explanation is not helpful to other users, no matter how correct it is. Stack Overflow is not a code sharing service. It’s a place for people to come and have questions answered. I know that you posted this out of good will to help others in your situation, and thanks for wanting to do that. Yet I’m afraid that your answer won’t be of help as it stands.

Move these two lines inside the loop. You need to reset these two values after each loop iteration.
for (int i=0; i<k; i++){
    currentGreatestValue = 0;
    Iterator hmIterator = hm.entrySet().iterator();


Thanks for the reply that was part of the issue also I was getting my key/values mixed up when I was removing in the loop I posted the answer below.

A couple issues I was comparing keys instead of values, the original code has get key stored as current value. Then I had to save the keys when I found the highest value to remove it after.

I posted the correct answer below you can see the difference.

Great. I only answered on why you are getting null pointer.
